# Define time of execution of integration-tests on jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, integration-testing

I got some integration tests on jenkins. Overall it takes about 30 minutes for them do run through. This takes too long. Therefore we are trying to find a way, to let one test class (which takes most of the time) be executed on another time. How can we achieve this?

At the moment we are including the tests in this way:

```
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>config</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>${skip.integration.test}</skip>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.class</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I heard something of activation profiles like these:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <jdk>1.4</jdk>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Do you have any idea how I can execute all tests but one test class every day, and on one day of the week execute all tests?

Answer (score 0):

I'd not skip integration tests for a few days. Because, the sooner your devs get feedback that one of their changes caused a test to fail the better. Corrections are applied quicker then since recent changes are remembered more easily. Otherwise also all other devs that depend on the culprit's changes develop against broken code or are even blocked for a longer period.

Do you mean that these integration tests do also run when your devs test their changes locally? I'd not recommend that and I do agree that *"about 30 minutes"* is definitely too long then.

See [Integration Testing With Maven](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/integration-testing-with-maven/) for an idea how to run unit tests and integration tests separately. (Yes, it's achieved with Maven profiles. See [Maven / Introduction to build profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).)

I'd use the `dev` profile mentioned there as default profile and use the `integration-test` profile on a CI system like Jenkins.